# Load an Image from the Gallery in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm currently doing a Widget in Android. It is on the market and it's free. 
I want to surprise the users by let them choose a picture they want to show in the widget.

Now...

If the widget is clicked, a PreferenceActivity appears. <-- Works!

In this Activity the user should be able to choose a picture from the phone picture gallery. <-- HOWTO?

After the User selected the prefered picture, the picture path or the drawable object should be stored in the SharedPreferences. <-- Would be really nice!

Is there any solution?

Thx!

Comment: What's a GalleryPictureChooserPreference? And where exactly are you having the difficulty; doesn't get clear from your question.

Comment: I looking for something like GalleryPictureChooserPreference. GalleryPictureChooserPreference doesn't exist. My Problem is that I don't know how to load a picture from the gallery. The user should be able to choose one picture from his own phone gallery and import it to the widget. The widget should then show the appropriate picture. Showing the picture will be no problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to get an image from the Gallery, you must send an intent to start up the Gallery for the user to choose an image as such

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
```

This will start the gallery and will call `onActivityResult` within your activity.